# "Saving" BigQuery Views for use in Tableau

Tags: view, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I'm trying to make faster dashboards in Tableau by creating views of my calculations directly in BigQuery.

Based on my understating if the gcloud documentation [here](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-ruby/docs/v0.4.0/Gcloud/Bigquery/View.html#class-Gcloud::Bigquery::View-label-View), the view will re-execute the query once it is accessed, so it kinda defeats my goal.*

*My goal is to eliminate calculations on the fly, be it in Tableau or BigQuery.

Is it possible to "save" these views, by way of scheduled scripts or workflows?

Thanks,

Comment: What's the reasoning you want to this? Sounds like you want to cache something, maybe write to a table the smaller data set and use that in your final query.

Comment: Hi, my goal is to simply pre-calculate and cache the data like you said, so Tableau won't be expelling server resources (and time) and just get the needed data from the table/view.

Comment: A view always reexecutes, but caching may solve your problem, if the underlying table remains the same it will not re-run, but rather return the cached result. Otherwise writing the results to a table might be what you want?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I'm not familiar with BigQuery caching though. Is it something I can set in the UI?

Comment: read about Tableau Extracts here: http://www.montage.co.nz/assets/Brochures/designing-efficient-workbooks2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A *view* is best thought of as a way to reformat a table to make it look more convenient to further queries. The query still has to run on BigQuery so the benefits will be that the view may look simpler to Tableau than the raw table (particularly convenient if the view uses some complex SQL to create some of its columns). But it won't save calculation time.

But, if your view is doing some complex *consolidation* of a larger table then it might be worth saving the results as a new table instead of creating a view. This is OK if your underlying table doesn't change frequently (rule of thumb if you use the results every day and the table changes weekly, it is probably worthwhile and certainly so if the changes are monthly). Then Tableau will be querying pre-consolidated results rather than the much larger raw table. BigQuery storage and processing is cheap so this is often a reasonable solution.

Another alternative is to use a Tableau *extract* to bring the data into your local drive or server. This is only practical if the table is small enough to fit locally and will only work really well for speed if it fits into local memory (which can be a lot more than you might think). But extracts, at least on Tableau server, can be set to refresh on a schedule, making much faster user interaction and absolving you of having to remember to manually update the consolidated table.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed explanation on this. We've initially had our dashboards use Tableau data extracts, but due to security concerns, we opted out of it. (login credentials are embedded to the TDE). So far, we're trying to use the queries generated by Tableau by running them on our raw tables, to generate a smaller data set from which Tableau can "feed" on.